# Error: "No route found for "GET /web/app_dev.php""

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, symfony-routing

I have created a bundle using the command `php app/console generate:bundle` this add the bundle in `/app/AppKernel.php` and also in `/app/config/routing.yml`. If I try to access the URL `http://devserver/web/app_dev.php/bank_homepage` I got a 404 error. I check `/app/logs/prod.log` and see this:

> [2013-07-29 13:41:27] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
>   route found for "GET /web/app_dev.php/bank_homepage"" at
>   /var/www/html/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1880
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No
>   route found for \"GET /web/app.php/bank_homepage\" at
>   /var/www/html/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1880,
>   Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException:  at
>   /var/www/html/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1222)"} []

What I'm doing wrong?

This is my `/app/config/routing.yml`

```
bank:
    resource: "@BankBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
....
```

And this is my `/src/BankBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`

```
bank_homepage:
    pattern:  /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: BankBundle:Default:index }
    requirements:
      _method: GET
```

**EDIT some tests**
I change the URL from `http://devserver/web/app_dev.php/bank_homepage` to `http://devserver/web/app_dev.php` and then the error changes to this:

> [2013-07-29 14:22:15] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
>   route found for "GET /web/app_dev.php"" at
>   /var/www/html/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1880
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No
>   route found for \"GET /web/app_dev.php\" at
>   /var/www/html/app/cache/prod/classes.php:1880,
>   Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException:  at
>   /var/www/html/app/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:1222)"} []

Which practically is the same

PS: I check (this)[No route found for "GET /portfolio but this didn't work for me

Comment: Please post your routing code.

Comment: @mattexx done, added to the main post

Comment: you access your website through `app_dev.php` and read the `prod.log`. Doesn't this ring a bell? :D

Comment: @cheesemacfly I don't have any dev log file altough I access the URL `_dev` for some reason logs go to `prod.log` file

Comment: maybe you are not really in dev mode. Have you tried clearing your cache after making the suggested change?

Comment: @mattexx already do that several times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your path to "bank_homepage":

```
bank_homepage:
    path:  /bank_homepage
    defaults: { _controller: BankBundle:Default:index }
    requirements:
        _method: GET
```

Make sure you are in dev mode:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

Comment: It looks like you are not in dev mode. Try switching to dev mode as above. I also changed "prefix" to "path" in my answer, bit not sure if that will do anything.

Comment: nothing still not working, I check `app/logs` directory after run the command suggested by you and logs are just one `prod.log`, what thing is causing my project stay out of `dev` enviroment?

Comment: I don't know, this is weird. Is your apache site pointed at symfony_root or symfony_root/web ?

Comment: @matexx I found the error, yes the problem was Apache Virtual Hosting it was pointing to another place

Comment: Great! can you GET /bank_homepage now?

Comment: yes, I can GET `/bank_homepage` I'm dealing with Twig and CSS and JS from my bundle but I'll open another topic for this, thanks for your support and time

Answer (score 1):

put another slash at the end of the pattern

Ex: **pattern: /hello/{name}/**